# Change footnotes crawling up the page

Tags: graphics, footnotes, layout

I inserted an image into my text and it is too big to fit on the page so it is placed on the next which is fine. However, the footnotes on the first page are now crawling up and are right below the last line of text on the original page. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using OverLeaf. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, without any code we cannot help. It depends on your document class and choice of preamble.

Comment: note that is a style decision not a bug so "change" would  be a better word to us than "fix"

Answer (score 1):

I inserted:

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

And footnotes are now always placed at the bottom.